# How to use TensorFlow for comparing key points?

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, pose-estimation

I am working on a fitness android application that would detect if a person has exercised correctly or not.

The app will record the person exercising, then compare it with the models, and display if the person has exercised correctly or not.

I have googled a lot about it; I came across many blogs/articles/posts that helped identify key points, but I couldn't find anything related to comparing the key points. I couldn't even find anything about comparing key points in images. All I could find was how TensorFlow detects keypoints or recognizes certain poses.
I also tried https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/train, but the pose estimation only has a  .js export for the web.

How will the machine be trained with the key points?
How will the key points be compared?
Can you suggest any other API that would be easier to understand and use in this regard?

I am new to TensorFlow and would highly appreciate it if someone can help me.

Comment: I would suggest asking this question on the [TensorFlow Lite discussion group](https://groups.google.com/u/1/a/tensorflow.org/g/tflite).

Comment: Okay, Thank you! @ShubhamPanchal